# In Chrome, getting a lot of 403 errors for individual elements on website when using https

Tags: google-chrome

In Chrome 62, getting a lot of 403 errors on https://www.mytotalconnectcomfort.com/ (Honeywell thermostat control) which randomly breaks the page... refreshing seems to give me different results, but still some are blocked. If I switch to http, it works fine.

I assume this is a misconfigured IIS server on their end. The site requires a user name and password for authentication.

My question: what is the issue and how can it be fixed locally or on the IIS server?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5JrGH.png

Some of request header:

```
GET /portal/Images/topheader_red_grey_line.jpg?1 HTTP/1.1
Host: www.mytotalconnectcomfort.com
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.89 Safari/537.36
Accept: image/webp,image/apng,image/*,*/*;q=0.8
DNT: 1
Referer: https://www.mytotalconnectcomfort.com/portal/Content/TrueHome/Site.css?v=2.5.21
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Cookie: __masterEUCookie=Set|mytotalconnectcomfort.com; LocalisationCultureCookie=en-US; RememberMe=...
```

Response header:

```
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Content-Type: text/html
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
Server: Web1
X-UA-Compatible: IE=edge
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Date: Sun, 12 Nov 2017 13:12:05 GMT
Content-Length: 1233
Set-Cookie: NSC_NZUDD-443-WT=ffffffff090ecc1d45525d5f4f58455ea42378b;expires=Sun, 12-Nov-2017 13:39:53 GMT;path=/;secure;httponly
```

Comment: This could be a problem in your Chrome, or it could be the vendor's problem.  Please try another browser and let us know if you get the same results.  Please also consider reporting the problem to the vendor.  Please try clearing cache, and confirming that your time zone / time is correct, on both your computer, and on your Honeywell.  Finally, please edit your question to indicate the OS you're using, and answers to the above questions and any other research you've done.

Comment: Tried in Firefox 57 with clear cache, same issue. Reported to vendor. Using Windows 10. Time Zone is correct. https://i.imgur.com/watrgx4.png To add... if I open the 403 resource manually in a new tab, it loads perfectly fine (200).

Comment: Not certain, although the fact that an individual element loads properly shortly after it gives a 403 points to a misbehaving web server on their end.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in firefox 65+.
After a while I found out that it was the new "webp" image format in the "Accept" header. Not all severs support it.
In my case (firefox) I changed the value of ***image.http.accept*** in ***about:config*** from

```
image/webp,*/*
```

to

```
image/png,image/*;q=0.8,*/*;q=0.5
```

I got these values from here [Accept values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Content_negotiation/List_of_default_Accept_values)

Comment: Did that indeed return 403 Forbidden, rather than some 400 Bad Request? (Also, the server _should_ ignore content types it does not know, but given that the above worked for you I guess that's not always true. Or maybe it's actually not related to removing webp, but due to the other changes.)